# Print Fixed Lines with Spring Shell

Tags: spring, spring-shell

I want to develop a small Sprint Shell project where I display static information which potentially updates when an event is received. Is this functionality possible with Spring Shell, or is it even the correct tool for the job?

To give an example of what I want to achieve:

```
-------------------
| Stock Value: 5$ | < This information should be always displayed
-------------------

shell:> I can put input here
```

While I type an event in the application should be able to change it to e.g.

```
-------------------
| Stock Value: 7$ | < This information gets updated
-------------------

shell:> I can still type here
```

Answer (score -1):

Spring shell can do that for you.

See the tutorial here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell/blob/master/spring-shell-docs/src/main/asciidoc/using-spring-shell.adoc